# Is there a way to create bind variables in Apache Superset's SQL Lab?

Tags: apache-superset

I've created a database where I'd like to track some of my financial data, and I've created a function in that database, which calculates the value of my portfolio since the first record. I'd like to create a dashboard in Apache Superset, to visualize my portfolio's value.

The function looks like this, and returns data like below:

```sql
select * from all_value_by_date_on_account(null, current_date, '<some currency>', <account-id-or-null>)
```

| date | Value | Money transacted | Free money | Performance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-03-17 | 98820 | 100000 | 755.6 | -0.004244 |
| 2020-03-31 | 98820 | 100000 | 755.6 | -0.004244 |
| 2020-04-01 | 187948.397923360635 | 225000 | 32052.7708519 | -0.02221702766550828889 |
| 2020-05-19 | 198110.048622676626 | 225000 | 30990.36516322 | 0.01822406127065167111 |

My question is, that is there a way to bind a dropdown's value into this function? I'd like to create a dropdown, where I'd list all the accounts, and if I select one of these accounts, Superset should bind its id into the `<account-id-or-null>` parameter.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Superset has support for SQL templating to achieve this

For example, you can retrieve the value for a specific filter as a list using `{{ filter_values() }}`

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE 
     account_id in ({{ "'" + "','".join(filter_values('account_id')) + "'" }})
```

Read through the doc for more details https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/sql-templating#available-macros